# netbeans wsdl client code generation

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans-7

Am trying to use netbeans to build a web service client. 
The remote WSDL has relative paths to the service and the schemaLocation.
Copied the wsdl localy, replaced the relative links and tried using it to generate the client.

```
Error: Unknown Host: localhost
URL Resource 
Retrieving Location:      locallink/Service.svc?xsd=xsd4 
    Found in document: remote url link Service.svc?xsd=xsd2
```

The error repeats for all the schema locations.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this... put all the files in the same directory. Remove the path information, so if you have `localhost/Service.svc?xsd=xsd4` replace that with `xsd4.xml`. It should be smart enough to look in the current directory for the linked files.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the new web service client, instead of selecting "Local File", select the "WSDL URL" option. This will automatically place the WSDL file where it needs to be.